# como mandar un correo que tenga de mensaje codigo html y php?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmailer

necesito mandar un correo donde el mensaje este con código html y PHP,
lo que hace el codigo en html es armar la tabla y con el php y mysql debe traer los datos y ponerlo en la tabla, cuando solo pongo html si manda el msj, cuando le pongo el php me sale error 500

le dejo el codigo

```
<?php
// Varios destinatarios
$para  = 'example@cisla.com';

// título
$título = 'Recordatorio ';


$enlace =  mysql_connect('192.168.1.15', 'bdas', '1452');
if (!$enlace) {
    die('No pudo conectarse: ' . mysql_error());
}
//echo 'Conectado satisfactoriamente';
mysql_select_db('aspatper_prueba') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT per.PERSC_Nombre as nombre , per.PERSC_ApellidoPaterno as apellido_paterno ,per.PERSC_ApellidoMaterno as apellido_materno
FROM cji_paciente pa
JOIN cji_persona per ON per.PERSP_Codigo = pa.PERSP_Codigo
JOIN cji_consulta con ON con.PACI_Codigo = pa.PACI_Codigo
JOIN cji_diagnostico dg ON dg.CONS_Codigo = con.CONS_Codigo
JOIN cji_diagnostico_fase dgf ON dgf.DIAG_Codigo = dg.DIAG_Codigo
JOIN cji_emprestablecimiento eme ON eme.EESTABP_Codigo = con.COMPP_Codigo
WHERE eme.EESTABP_Codigo =  "11"
AND dgf.FASDIA_TipoDias =  "2"/* FASDIA_TipoDias=0 lunes a sabado(fase 1) FASDIA_TipoDias=1 lun-mir-vier FASDIA_TipoDias=2 mar-jue-sa FASDIA_TipoDias=3 lu a sabado */
AND dgf.FASDIA_FlagFase =  "1"
AND con.PROD_Codigo =  "30852"
AND NOT 
EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM cji_consulta
WHERE PACI_Codigo = pa.PACI_Codigo
AND CONS_FechaRegistro = CURDATE( )
)';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());

// mensaje
$mensaje = '
<html>

 <head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

 <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">

 <tr>

     <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding: 40px 0 30px 0;">

     <img src="http://www.aspatperu.org.pe/AspatPeru.png" alt="Creating Email Magic" width="300" height="230" style="display: block;" />

 </td>

 </tr>

 <tr>

<td bgcolor="#ffffff">

 <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<tr>

 <td>

   BIENVENIDO AL SISTEMA SISBIO-TB

 </td>

</tr>   

<tr>

 <td style="padding: 20px 0 30px 0;font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    PACIENTES QUE NO ASISTIERON A SU TRATAMIENTO EL DIA DE HOY :
    <br>

<br>
<table border="1">  
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
        <th>Aperllido Materno</th>
      </tr>'
          while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))

          {

      '<tr>
        <td>'echo $row[0]'</td>
        <td>'echo $row[1]'</td>
        <td>'echo $row[2]'</td>
      </tr>'
     }
  '</table>

 </td>

</tr>


 </table>

</td>

 </tr>



</table>

</body>


</html>
';

// Para enviar un correo HTML, debe establecerse la cabecera Content-type
$cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .="Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

// Cabeceras adicionales
$cabeceras .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'From: Recordatorio <cumples@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Enviarlo
mail($para, $título, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buenas tardes.

Fíjate que el problema que estas teniendo, es que al armar la variable mensaje estas incluyendo ahí adentro el código php, cuando en realidad deberías armar el principio de la cadena, concatenar el contenido de la tabla, y después agregar el final de la cadena.

```
    // mensaje
    $mensaje = '
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    ...
    <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
        <th>Aperllido Materno</th>
    </tr>';
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $mensaje .= '
        <tr>
            <td>' .$row[0].'</td>
            <td>' .$row[1].'</td>
            <td>' .$row[2].'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    $mensaje .= '</table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>...';
```

Por favor, tambien tene en cuenta los riesgos en la seguridad al ejecutar los querys, mira el siguiente [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: gracias por la ayuda y el consejo