# ¿Como enviar un correo?

Tags: php, html, email

Necesito hacer un cotizador que al introducir los datos me vaya guardando cada cotización con el mismo formulario, que imprima los datos en pantalla pero a la vez los guarde en una variable y al momento de dar clic a un botón le envíe al cliente un correo con los datos. Ya sé conectarlo y recibir los input pero necesito enviar esa información por correo.

¿Como lo hago?

Comment: Posible duplicada https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/63644/38468

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar la libreria [PHPmailer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) descomprime en la carpeta de tu proyecto y configura tus datos necesarios en un script php. Es indispensable que tu cuenta gmail este configurada para acceso a conexiones menos seguras.

```js
    <?php
    
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    
    require ("class.phpmailer.php");
    require ("class.smtp.php");
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Username = "TU_CORREO@gmail.com"; 
    $mail->Password = "TU_PASSWORD"; 
     
    
    
     $mail->IsHTML(true);
    
    
    $mail->addAddress(CORREO_DEL_DESTINATARIO);
    
    $mail->Subject = "EL_asunto";
    $mail->Body = "EL_mensaje";
    
    
    $exito = $mail->Send();
    
    if($exito){
    echo 'El correo fue enviado correctamente';
    }else{
    echo 'Hubo un inconveniente. Intente de nuevo.';
    }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: pero no es el envio lo que necesito, es como hago para que el cotizador se ejecute varias veces y vaya acumulando los datos, el envio lo tengo claro

Comment: se me vienen algunas ideas, tal vez que tu pagina se actualice dinamicamente y que almacenes tus datos en un array, al final lo recuperas y lo agregas en el body del correo, pero podrias mostrar como es tu codigo.

Comment: Me cambiaste mi encabezado y no es lo que necesito

Comment: Gracias, la verdad soy muy novato en esto pero como me lo acabas de plantear me parece super me podrias un ejemplo de como recuperar ese array y como lo voy guardando?